# asp List view Data pager on page properties changing event not working

Tags: c#, listview, datapager

I am using a data pager along with a list view. On initial load everything is working fine, but when I try to navigate to other pages, then the grid becomes empty.

I have already bound my results in `pre_render` event. When I tried to debug, I found that the `OnPagePropertiesChanged` and `OnPageProPertiesChanging` events are not fired at all.

It's looking weird.

Comment: Share your code so the problem could be traced.

Comment: `OnPageProPertiesChanging` has a case error in it, I expect it should be `OnPagePropertiesChanging`.